# how to select foreign language on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm not able to select foreign language from MySQL :(

when I search `SELECT *  FROM`ml_table`WHERE`word`= 'അംഗങ്ങളായ'` 
result is "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0433 sec)"
like this

let me tell you one thing my table is a collection of Malyalam words, which so BIG
my table structure like this 
[image]

Comment: Is there data in your table that would match your query?  This may sound like a stupid comment, but I myself got caught by this quite a few times

Comment: @Aleks G  Yes, there is. It is working fine when I search based on id. you can try here [link]http://www.chatfitness.com/search.php?en=aa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's obviously not going to translate anything for you. But if your columns support UTF, and the record exists, it will be found.

Comment: it is working when I search based ml_id. 
at the same time select 'word' doesn't :(

Comment: what if you copy and paste 'word' in the select clause?

Comment: result is same :( 

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0006 sec )

Comment: does the terminal that you are writing the query in support utf?